# make psychopy builder wait for a response after every 3 images

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, response, psychopy

I am making an experiment where a participant see's 1 image, a mask, then another image and needs to make a button press while the 3rd image is on the screen and the experiment should not move on until they make a response.

I am not sure if i should use 1 routine and specify the start time of the wait for response to be after the first two images are shown, or do i make two different routines within a loop, where the second routine has the wait for response?

I have tried making three separate routines one for each of the images i want to show, but i get an error where the third routine with the wait for response can't find the conditions file i specified in the loop.

Comment: All routines within a loop have access to the variables within the loop's conditions file. To understand what is actually happening here, you would need to post the content of the error message that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You have flexibility to do things a number of ways here. The simplest, though, would be a single routine:

- specified onset time and duration for both the first image and the mask.
- specified onset time for the second image but no offset time specified (so it will be visible indefinitely).
- specified onset time for the keyboard component and no offset time specified, but have that component set to "Force end of routine".